# POST binary data using httplib cause Unicode exceptions

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, httplib

When i try to send an image with urllib2 the UnicodeDecodeError exception is occured.

HTTP Post body:

```python
f = open(imagepath, "rb")
binary = f.read()
mimetype, devnull = mimetypes.guess_type(urllib.pathname2url(imagepath))

body = """Content-Length: {size}
Content-Type: {mimetype}

{binary}
""".format(size=os.path.getsize(imagepath),  
           mimetype=mimetype,
           binary=binary)

request = urllib2.Request(url, body, headers)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=1))
response = opener.open(request)
print response.read()
```

Traceback :

```python
   response = opener.open(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1181, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 973, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1007, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 827, in _send_output
    msg += message_body
  File "/home/usertmp/biogeek/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 49: invalid start byte
```

python version 2.7.5

Anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: I don't get in what line you're getting the exception

Comment: @PauloBu i am getting the exception at opener.open(request) line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to send a body containing headers and content. If you want to send content type and content length, you need to do it in the headers, not in the body:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': mimetype, 'Content-Length', str(size)}
request = urllib2.Request(url, data=binary, headers=headers)
```

If you don't set the Content-Length header, it will be automatically set to the size of `data`

As to your error: it's happening on the line

```
msg += message_body
```

This error can only happen, if one of these two strings is `unicode`, and the other `str` containing `\xff`, as in that case the latter will be automatically coecred to unicode using `sys.getdefaultencoding()`.

My final guess would be: `message_body` here is your `data`, which is a `str` and contains `\xff` somewhere. `msg` is what has been passed to the HTTPConnection earlier, namely the headers, and they are unicode because you either used unicode for at least one key in your headers (the values are converted to `str` earlier), or you have imported `unicode_literals` from `__futures__`.

Comment: thank you very much, i avoid the unicode exception like that :
    request = urllib2.Request(url.encode("utf-8"), data=binary, headers=headers)
this is a clean way to solve the problem?

Comment: just not tu use unicode for headers or url. urls should be percent encoded, and headers should be iso-8859-1 or encoded according to [rfc 2047](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2047#section-8). My best advice would be: use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) if possible, it's way better in dealing with unicode.